# Online keyboard adding space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a working keyboard without plugins on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dM3Gs/6/). I have created the keyboard, now I am adding the spacebar. As you may have guessed, when you click the spacebar, I want it to add a space. I tried this with the following code:

```
if ($('.space').click() == true) {
  $('h1').append(' ');
}
```

For all buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function() {
         $('h1').append(this.textContent);
     });
});
```

but this doesn't allow any of the buttons to function properly. Will this code work, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: what do you mean in `but this doesn't allow any of the buttons to function properly`?

Comment: In earlier versions, the buttons would append their text to the h1, but that doesn't happen

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/v9WpS/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('button').click(function() {
             if(this.textContent == 'Space'){
              $('h1').append('&nbsp;');
             }else{
              $('h1').append(this.textContent);
             }
         });
    });
```

Comment: This does not add a space but a no-break space. They are two different characters. Although they might in some context both be used, and no-break space might even be better, the question asks for a space.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Just out of curiosity, how would a non breaking space effect this situation in particular? I don't see a downside to it.

Comment: @imbondbaby, a no-break space by definition prevents line breaks before and after, a normal space allows it. This can surely matter if the content is longer than the available width. This why many keyboard layouts let you enter either a space or (e.g. using the AltGr key) the no-break space. The point is that the two are not the same, and you should not artitrarily substitute for the other.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  I see what you are saying now... Good question by the OP cause I can't figure it out :p

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to replace `<button class='space'>Space</button>` by

```
<button class='space'> </button>
```

A space bar normally does not contain any text, and does not need any text.

If you really want to have visible text in the space bar and you use `button` elements, add a value attribute to the space bar button,

```
<button class='space' value='space'>Space</button>
```

and use the following code (which just uses a `value` attribute if it exists, otherwise the text content of a button):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function() {
         $('h1').append(this.value || this.textContent);
     });
});
```

This approach is more flexible, since this way you can make the letter buttons have uppercase letters like A in them but still make them add lowercase letters, which is what keyboards normally do. You would then use `<button class='a' value='a'>A</button>` etc. (You probably don’t need the `class` attributes, by the way.)